# Using a function with an interval to change a class of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, intervals

I'm trying to create a simple game that has a function that selects a random div(out of a selection)and then sets a random countdown using an interval and when the countdown hits 0 the class of that div will change. 
Then i have it so when you click on something assigned with that class it will change back to the original class.

At the moment when i'm running my code the divs seem to be changing after the countdown but won't change when i click them.
But my main problem is that the main function that changes the random divs is only running once.

The divs ("box") start as .wait

My code:

```js
var react = function(){
    var box = parseInt(Math.random()*64);

    while($("box"+box).hasClass("now")) {
        box = parseInt(Math.random()*64);
    }

    var timer = parseInt((Math.random()*10)+2);

    var countdown=setInterval(function(){
        timer-=1
        $("#box"+box).text(parseFloat(timer.toFixed(0)));

        if(timer<=0){
            clearInterval(countdown)
            $("#box"+box).text("");
            $("#box"+box).text("");
            $("#box"+box).removeClass("wait");
            $("#box"+box).addClass("now");
        }
    },1000)
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //paint\\
    //$(".wait").click(function() {
    //$(this).toggleClass("now")
    //})
    //paint\\

    setInterval(react(),1000);

    $(".now").click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("now");
        $(this).addClass("wait");
    })
})
```

Comment: BTW: Your Selector is wrong:
`while($("box"+box).hasClass("now")){` is missing a `#`to select an element by ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "But my main problem is that the main function that changes the random divs is only running once."

i'm assuming that you're referring to the following line.

```
setInterval(react(), 1000);
```

modify it as follows:

```
setInterval(react, 1000);
```

*update:*

assuming you've a fixed number of div, you can assign a common handler for all of them at page load like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('your-common-div-selector').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("now")&& !$(this).hasClass("wait")) {
      this.removeClass("now");
      this.addClass("wait");
  });
});
```

Comment: The issue with calling `.click` within the  the setInterval is that if the random div selected is one that's been selected before, you're binding yet another `click` event to the same element. That'll cause the element to trigger the callback twice (and so on - depending on how random the random selector truly is...)

Comment: The clicking now works, but the interval still won't happen more than once, i tried what you suggested and it just froze everything

Answer (score 1):

The issue is how you're binding your `click` event. You'll want to [delegate](https://api.jquery.com/on/) that event, rather than use `click()`.

When `setInterval` runs, it adds a class, 'new' to an element. However, since no elements had that class name (when calling `click()` in $doc.ready), no handler is triggered.

First, a fiddle demonstrating this works: http://jsfiddle.net/yvvMp/

Here's an example using your code + delegating the events:

```
var react = function(){
    var box = parseInt(Math.random()*64);

    while($("#box"+box).hasClass("now")) {
        box = parseInt(Math.random()*64);
    }

    var timer = parseInt((Math.random()*10)+2);

    var countdown=setInterval(function(){
        var $el = $('#box' + box);

        timer-=1
        $el.text(parseFloat(timer.toFixed(0)));

        if(timer<=0){
            clearInterval(countdown);

            $el.text("")
               .removeClass("wait")
               .addClass("now");
        }
    },1000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $parent = $('.parent-to-now-elements') // $('body') works, but not as efficient
    setInterval(react, 1000);

    $parent.on('click', '.now', function(){
        $(this).removeClass("now");
        $(this).addClass("wait");
    })
})
```

Tilwin's answer will work, but you run into the chance that the same element could have multiple event handlers bound. Depending on how long the game runs, and how often a user gets the same DIV element randomly selected, your DOM could look something like:

`<div class='wait wait wait wait wait wait wait wait wait'></div>`

Worse, each time jQuery calls the click handler, you're forcing the browser to touch the DOM (depending on the game, this could be bad!)

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pjMcv/
(When a block turns green, click it. Then wait for it to turn red again and click...)

(Tilwin has edited his answer, removing `.click` out of `setInterval`. His edited answer is better, but it still has a downside - it requires n number of event bindings. Works for simple games, but if your game has 1000 squares, you'll have 1000 event handlers)

Comment: How did you delegate your click event? I'm assuming something like: `$('.parent_element').on('click', 'now', function(){ /* logic */ })` ? - I'll update my answer with a bit more explanation...

Comment: @user3378151 - No problem. I created a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/yvvMp/) demonstrating that it does work. Good luck with the game!